# Error CORS en REACT + AXIOS

Tags: reactjs, post, http, axios

Estoy armando mi primer app con REACT, y tengo que hacer una peticion POST a una dirección. Estoy usando axios, pero me sale el siguiente error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://PRUEBA.org/' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. (la url es de ejemplo, no la real).
En network me sale abajo el codigo 200 en el estatus, pero que el Header fue deshabilitado por la preflight response de CORS.

Este es el codigo de la funcion que se llama en un elemento form en un evento onSubmit:

```
async function sendData(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const config = {
            url: 'http://PRUEBA.org/',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD, Authorization, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({email: email, password: password}),
        };
        const response = await axios(config).catch((err) => err);
        if(response.data.error){
            alert(response.data.error);
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
            setIsAuthorized(true);
        }
    }
```

Lei muchos posts pero ninguno de los headers que dicen para agregar sirvio, sigue dando error. Y si borro el "access-control-allow-origin", me da error 401.
Aclaro que se comunica a una api de terceros a la cual no tengo acceso.
Soy super nuevo en esto. Toda ayuda se agradece!

Comment: Buenas yo hace tiempo tambien tuve el mimo problema en react y es que basicamente con las ultimas versiones del protocolo http en u api o a donde hagas un fetch siempre que se salga del puerto, por ejemplo. Si tiene una api en el puerto 4000 y tu web en el 3000 te dara este error lo unico que tienes que hacer es configurar cors, que es digamos como un controlador de quien puede hacer peticiones y nada mas.

Answer (score 1):

No se pueden enviar peticiones desde localhost porque localhost esta dentro de la red privada y solo con una red pública o más bien una ip pública o accesible por tcp se puede hacer lo que usted desea.
Tiene varias opciones la primera montar su propio servidor casero, la segunda subir la aplicación a azure, aws o heroku y la tercera que no garantizo que funcione pero le podría funcionar es usar un servidor proxy. Inténtelo con este código modificado, la url cambio por una que contiene al inicio la url del servidor proxy que se va a encargar de hacer la petición por usted siempre y cuando ese servidor proxy este funcionando y para ello se necesita la cabecera 'origin':'x-requested-with'. Puede encontrar más al respecto en : https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere. Código:

```
async function sendData(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const config = {
            url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://PRUEBA.org/',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'origin':'x-requested-with',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD, Authorization, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({email: email, password: password}),
        };
        const response = await axios(config).catch((err) => err);
        if(response.data.error){
            alert(response.data.error);
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
            setIsAuthorized(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Richard! Con esas modificaciones ya utilizo el proxy? No lo debo instalar en package.json o algo así?

Comment: Actualizo que puse este código tal cual pero sigue dando error! Ya no se que inventar, lo tendré que cargar en un servidor?

Comment: Pero http://PRUEBA.org/ si es la url donde quiere hacer la petición??? No debería poner la url del API que es ?? Digo pregunto y si no le funciona así le toca montarlo en un heroku se lo recomiendo es gratuito y lo podría usar para probar su app. Sin embargo sospecho que esa url de http://PRUEBA.org/ no es la que tiene que poner ahí o sí ?? Intente esto : en un navegador escriba: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos . Eso es un api json placeholder que es gratis y eso le va a devolver este mensaje:

Comment: Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with. Si luego intenta eso mismo en postman y le agrega esa cabecera entonces le va a devolver los datos. Posiblemente alguna cabecera le este afectando. Lea este archivo: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/. Sino le funciona de todos modos mejor suba el app a heroku gratuitamente y ahí debería poder probarla siempre y cuando esa url (PRUEBA.org) de verdad sea la correcta

Comment: Richard fuiste muy amable! Descargue una extensión de Chrome que se llama MOESIF CORS y me permitió hacer peticiones perfectamente! Ya está solucionado, dejo este comentario por si alguno le sirve. Nuevamente mil gracias!

Comment: me ayudo instalar la extension de chrome MOESIF CORS, gracias por el aporte