# ¿Como puedo corregir el error de cors?

Tags: reactjs, cors, react-axios

Quiero hacer esta peticion tipo GET en react el api que voy a consumir es un API privada pero el dominio de la peticion es diferente a localhost:3000 puse el header de control de acceso y no funciona que mas puedo agregar

Adjunto codigo

```
   import axios from 'axios';


  var config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://exmaple.com/api',
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': '',
    'Acces-Controll-Allow-Origin': '*',
  },
};

function Get(){
  axios(config)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
Get();

export default Get
```

Que tendria que agregar o como podria hacer la peticion para que funcione cabe recalcar que este es el back de la pagina

imagenes del error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: prueba a lanzar la app en https en lugar de en http. En el terminal de vscode en lugar de poner npm start usa `set HTTPS=true&&npm start`

Comment: me mando un error

Comment: listo lo corri asi y no funcionio

Comment: Mira este post https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/463756/error-cors-en-react-axios?rq=1

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)